# What is the max number of the shortest path in a complete graph？

Tags: graph-theory

Give a complete graph $K_n$(the edge of the graph has positive weight), define the max number of the shortest paths between two vertices to be the number of paths that have the same length and the length is the shortest among any other paths.
I come across two questions.

1. define x to be the number of the shortest path between two vertices a and b. a and b is considered to be a vertex pair. How to set the edge weight to reach the max sum of the number of shortest path when considering K vertex pairs, notice that K vertex pairs have 2*K different vertices？

   2. consider all vertex pairs which consist $C_n^2$ vertex pairs,notice that one vertex can belong to one or many vertex pairs. How to set the edge weight to reach the max sum of the number of shortest path？

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking: In a complete graph, all vertices are connected, by an edge, so there is always a unique shortest path of length 1.

Comment: The first line of the question reads "the edge of the graph has positive weight". This means that edges can have all sorts of length (any real number). It is standard to define the length of a path as the sum of the weight of the edges. The only thing which is not clear is whether positive means $>0$ or $\geq 0$.

Comment: The edge weight is always larger than 0,and the number of shortest path from a to b means   between a and b there may be 4 path which are  4;1,1,1,1;2,3;1,4 then the shortest distance between a and b is obviously 4,and 4 and 1,1,1,1 these two paths both have length 4. These numbers reprrsent the edge weight of the path, now I can change the edge weight that I can change the path 2,3 into the path2,2,so the number of my shortest paths increase by 1. The problem is how to choose the edge weight of the graph.